# Does following syntax consider basic type as integer?

Tags: c++

```
typedef unsigned xyz_t;
```

here xyz_t is user defined name.

Is 'integer' implicit in this case?

Comment: The `typedef` specifies that `xyz_t` is an alias (alternative name for) the type `unsigned`.    `unsigned` is an integral type.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099830/unsigned-keyword-in-c

Answer (score 5):

`unsigned` is the short way of writing `unsigned int`. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) for a more complete list of integer types and their equivalent ways to write them.

After the typedef `xyz_t` is an alias for `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2):

Per [Table 11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.simple#tab:simple.type.specifiers) of N4659 (the C++17 standard final draft):

> ```
> Specifier(s)  Type
>
> [...]
> unsigned      “unsigned int”
> unsigned int  “unsigned int” 
> [...]
> ```

Therefore, `unsigned` has exactly the same meaning as `unsigned int` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`xyz_t` in this context is declared to be a type alias to `unsigned int` type.
If `xyz_t` is previously declared in the same scope to be some other, non basic data type, then this code will cause compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

`unsigned` is the same as `unsigned int`.

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.